# Keycloak and ReactJS: Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message

Tags: reactjs, iframe, keycloak

I copied this repo with a working example of Keycloak inside ReactJS: https://github.com/Qodestackr/keycloak-app

The difference is that my Keycloak server is not running locally but on an external amazon server. I logged on to the admin console and exported the Keycloak OICD JSON adapter config (some info removed for security reasons):

```
{
  "realm": "*******-employees",
  "auth-server-url": "https://dev.iam.******.com/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "serviceapp",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "***************************"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

First thing I noticed was that the secret is in the keycloak.json file. This cannot be intended in ReactJS because it runs client side and the users could download the file and figure out the client-secret. Second thing I noticed, when running the project, was that without manually adding the clientId to keycloak.json it throws a missing clientId error.

Anyhow, when I run this code and click login, it says "Initializing Keycloak..." for about 20-30 seconds and then the console throws the following warning and error respectively:

```
No routes matched location "/undefined/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html"
```

.

```
Uncaught (in promise) {error: 'Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message.'}
```

In my Resources.jsx I tried setting checkLoginIFrame to false (this seems to solve the problem for most people), but this only removes the "Initializing Keycloak..." message and still nothing happens.

I also tried updating my keycloak.json to camel casing as suggested by some:

```
{
  "realm": "*******-employees",
  "authServerUrl": "https://dev.iam.******.com/",
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "resource": "serviceapp",
  "verifyTokenAudience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "***************************"
  },
  "useResourceRoleMappings": true,
  "confidentialPort": 0,
  "clientId": "serviceapp"
}
```

Comment: I believe this could be a bug in keycloak

Comment: So, is this issue fixed? I have same problems

Comment: Nope. I ended up working around it, resulting in unsafe code...

Comment: You can disable the session status iframe by setting the `checkLoginIframe` option to `false` when calling `keycloak.init()`. At least this solved the issue in my app. See [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#session-status-iframe) for details.

Comment: Hey thanks, unfortunately the company went bankrupt, but will use this for future reference.